# How foreach array of object that actually field of another object?

Tags: php, foreach

I have such data structure of object:

```
"site":"http://mercurygold.com.ua/",
"shops":[
      { 
         "id":"1",
         "shopLogo":"mercuryGoldShop1",
         "address":"test test test"
      },
      { 
         "id":"2",
         "shopLogo":"mercuryGoldShop2",
         "address":"text text text"
      }
   ]
```

How can I foreach all 'shops' objects without addressing fields by names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it with 2 `foreach` loops. Assuming "shops" is in variable `$var`, you can access it like this:

```
foreach($var['shops'] as $shop)
{
   foreach($shop as $key=>$val)
   {
      echo $key . ": " . $val . "\n";
   }
}
```

Note: If the variable is JSON you will have to do `$var = json_decode($var);` first.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sure you it's a **JSON format**, to get elements `shops` you need to do this :

```
<?php

  $var = '
  {
      "site":"http://mercurygold.com.ua/",
      "shops":[
      { 
         "id":"1",
         "shopLogo":"mercuryGoldShop1",
         "address":"test test test"
      },
      { 
         "id":"2",
         "shopLogo":"mercuryGoldShop2",
         "address":"text text text"
      }
   ]
 }';

 $var = json_decode($var); 
 foreach($var->shops as $shop)
 {
     foreach($shop as $key=>$val)
     {
        echo $key . ": " . $val . "\n";  
     }
     echo '<br>';
 }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id: 1 shopLogo: mercuryGoldShop1 address: test test test
id: 2 shopLogo: mercuryGoldShop2 address: text text text
```